# Codec management on API < 16

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to manage video encoding on a device with Android 4.0.4 (API15). Unfortunatly Android MediaCodec was included on API 16.

How can I work with video codecs on a API15 devices? I am not finding any information.

Thanks

Comment: If it is just one device it may be easier to find a custom ROM with a higher API level. Then you could simply use the MediaCodec API.

Comment: It is not only one device, but one model of devices. But it was a good idea.